# Gutenberg Block: Allowing Bulletted and Numbered Lists in Wordpress RichText

Tags: wordpress, html-lists, richtext

How to use HTML Unordered or Ordered Lists in allowedFormats attribute in Wordpress RichText ? Or there exists some other way to include this feature in RichText component ?

Comment: To my knowledge the format for lists does not exist. So you cannot use it in RichText.
However this should solve what you are looking for: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/
Create a custom format, and then add that. It's a bit more work on your side, but a clean and solid solution.